# Cant use Delphi 2007 on win7 64Bits

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

This is really wierd i can open Delphi 2007 without any errors but i can't start a new project or even open an excisting one. i tried reïnstalling 3 time without any succes and also i tried the WOW64x debugger for win7 64 bits and also with no succes.

when i do 'projects/newproject' i dont have any options to choose from i can only choose 'project group' or 'text'. When i choose project group i get the error 'acces violation 00000000'.

Comment: Did you install any extra add-ons? What anti-virus program?

Answer (score 3):

I am using D2007 on 7 64 bit, there are some issues sometimes with the debugger, but it works. Did you install the available updates?

Comment: Do you get a stack trace from the IDE? As suggested, try to remove any third party add-on that may have been installed.

Comment: nopes i dont get anything and i cant do anything is it possible it has something to do with my rights on the network?

Comment: Rights on the network? Are you storing/accessin some Delphi files from the network?